# 504 после загрузки большого количества файлов

Tags: postgresql, nginx, ruby-on-rails, transaction, puma

В рельсовом приложении есть код, который обрабатывает загрузку файлов.
Суть в следующем:
Какое-то кол-во файлов отправляется с формы, попадает на сервер, вызывается транзакция, в которой создается пара записей в БД и файлы сохраняются в Google Cloud.
Файлы могут быть относительно большими (до 50 мб каждый).
При загрузке на продакшене примерно 200 мегабайт (10 файлов) появляется проблема:
Все файлы загружены, но в ответ от запроса пользователю приходит 504 ошибка, в логах ничего криминального - маршруты и запросы к бд.

При дебаггинге и тестировании обнаружил, что во время или после загрузки, с api, которое работает в том же приложении приходит 504 ошибка на клиент:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError
could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.001 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема, пробовал следующее:

- Увеличить `pool` до 50 в `database.yml`
- Увеличить `checkout_timeout` до 10 минут в `database.yml`
- Увеличить `client_max_body_size` в nginx до пары гигабайт
- Увеличить `keepalive_timeout` до 10 минут
- Увеличить `keepalive_requests` до 100
- Увеличить таймаут в `config/puma.rb` до 10 минут
- Увеличить кол-во тредов в `config/puma.rb` до 10 при 2-х воркерах.

Возможно, дело в Google Cloud, но я даже не знаю где и как можно посмотреть логи или другие подробности загрузки файлов.

П.С. я понимаю, что долгие запросы лучше обрабатывать асинхронно но задачу нужно решить именно в таком кейсе.

Comment: А в `postgresql.conf` какой `max_connections`?  Ну и да, убедитесь, что нет какого-то ручного лазанья в базу без закрытия итераторов.

Comment: proxy_read_timeout?

Answer (score 0):

следующие настройки помогли. подозреваю, что на самом деле пригодилась только последняя строчка.

postgresql.conf

```
tcp_keepalives_idle = 60
tcp_keepalives_interval = 1
tcp_keepalives_count = 5
```

конфиг nginx

```
    send_timeout 600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
```